# Complex SQL Select SOD with InnerJoin

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, inner-join

how are you? I'm trying to deploy a complex SQL select.

Tables:

**USER (there's a boolean that tell us if its an USER or a profile) (nombre is PK)**

```
nombre        is_user
pedro            1
P_Facturacion    0
P_Administracion 0
```

**REL_USERPROFILE (relation between an user and its profiles) (PK composed by username and profile name)**

```
Pedro P_Facturacion
Pedro P_Administracion
```

**DUTY (a duty have multiple profiles, in the example only one.)(id autoincremental PK)**

```
Facturar P_Facturacion
Administrar P_Administracion
```

**MATRIX (a matrix have 2 duties that are in a risk. this use the duty id like FK and matrix PK is an autoincrement)**

```
Facturar Administrar Critical(risk)
```

Well, i have to select all the user that have to profiles with dutys in a risk.
To explain it better, i need to select all the user that have profiles related with the duties Facturacion and administracion at the same time in this example.

An result example is.
**Pedro Facturar Administrar Critical**

Thank you!

Comment: "I'm trying to deploy a complex SQL select" or... are you trying to find someone that will write it for free? StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592).
Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a
[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). :)

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: i update with an not working solution

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
            primerset.conflicto,
            primerset.operador1,
            primerset.duty1,
            primerset.P1,
            segundoset.duty2,
            segundoset.P2,
            primerset.criticidad,
            primerset.descripcion
          FROM
            ((SELECT Rel_Operador_Perfil.operador  AS 'operador1', Rel_Operador_Perfil.sucursal_operador as 'sucursal1', Duty.nombre AS 'duty1', Matriz.criticidad AS 'criticidad',
                Matriz.conflicto AS 'conflicto', Rel_Duty_Perfil.perfil as 'P1', Matriz.descripcion as 'descripcion'
             FROM (Rel_Operador_Perfil
              INNER JOIN Rel_Duty_Perfil ON Rel_Operador_Perfil.Operador_Perfil = Rel_Duty_Perfil.perfil
              INNER JOIN Duty ON Rel_Duty_Perfil.idduty = Duty.id
              INNER JOIN Matriz ON Duty.id = Matriz.duty1 ))AS primerset
          INNER JOIN
            (SELECT Rel_Operador_Perfil.operador as 'operador2',Rel_Operador_Perfil.sucursal_operador as 'sucursal2', Duty.nombre AS 'duty2', Rel_Duty_Perfil.perfil as 'P2'
              FROM(Rel_Operador_Perfil
              INNER JOIN Rel_Duty_Perfil ON Rel_Operador_Perfil.Operador_Perfil = Rel_Duty_Perfil.perfil
              INNER JOIN Duty ON Rel_Duty_Perfil.idduty = Duty.id
              INNER JOIN Matriz ON Duty.id = Matriz.duty2 )) AS segundoset
          ON primerset.operador1 =  segundoset.operador2)
          GROUP BY primerset.operador1, primerset.duty1, segundoset.duty2, primerset.conflicto, primerset.criticidad,primerset.P1,segundoset.P2,primerset.descripcion
          ORDER BY primerset.operador1`enter code here`
```

This is my solution, but only work when i have only 1 relation between duties on the matrix.
When i have multiple relation, it show me cross risk users.. example

i say
Billing vs Delivery processing
Sales order processing vs Billing

and the tool show me Billing vs Billing to.